# htaccess multiple domains web redirect to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have an iweb shared web hosting service and i've multiples domains name that i'd like to 
point in differents folders in  /public_html.
For example, i want the web site:
www.one.com to points on /public_html/one
www.two.com to points on /public_html/two
www.three.com to points on /public_html/three
I don't have the option on my cpanel and i'm trying with .htaccess 
can you help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think what you want to do is possible.  If you have a dedicated server you can do this, but not on a shared server.  You will need to set this up by asking your host.